# Derivatives 1, 2 and 3 and limits

Tags: limits, derivatives

A question for you.
Show that if $\lim_{x\to+\infty} x\,f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} x\,f''(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to+\infty} x\,f'(x)=0$
Thanks ;)

Comment: Up to now, I can show that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0$

First we see that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f''(x)=0$ . This comes from  $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{xf(x)}{x}=[\frac{0}{+\infty}]=0$.

Then we show that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0$. In fact we have $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{xf''(x)-f'(x)+f'(x)}{1}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}xf''(x)=0$. So $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x}+\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x>0$. By Taylor's theorem there exists $\xi_x \in (x,x+1)$ such that
$$
f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_x).
$$
Multiply by $x$ and rearrange to get
\begin{align*}
xf'(x) &= xf(x+1)-xf(x)-\frac{1}{2}xf''(\xi_x)\\
\implies |xf'(x)| &\leq |xf(x+1)|+|xf(x)|+\frac{1}{2}|xf''(\xi_x)|\\
&\leq |(x+1)f(x+1)|+|xf(x)|+\frac{1}{2}|xf''(\xi_x)|\\
\end{align*}
By assumption, given $\epsilon>0$, we can find $M_1>0$ and $M_2>0$ such that $x \geq M_1$ implies $|xf(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and $x\geq M_2$ implies $|x f''(x)|<\epsilon$.

Then, $x \geq \max\{ M_1+1, M_2+1\}$ implies
\begin{align*}
|xf'(x)| &\leq |(x+1)f(x+1)|+|xf(x)|+\frac{1}{2}|xf''(\xi_x)|\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{4}+\frac{\epsilon}{4} +\frac{1}{2} |\xi_x f''(\xi_x)|\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon\\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, by definition, $\lim_{x\to \infty} x f'(x) = 0$.